# Conditions of the vector-calculus Green's theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

While studying [the Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), I think a lot about whether there is an abundance of the condition (now called $X$) of

> $X:\quad$ $P$ and $Q$ (in the Wikipedia article, $L$ and $M$) have continuous, first-order partial derivatives.

In the proof in *simple* cases of the theorem (in the Wikipedia article), it seems that we only need

> $X':\quad$ $P$ has the integrable $y$-partial derivative, and $Q$ has the integrable $x$-partial derivative.

So, **my question**: Can the condition $X$ of the Green's theorem be extended to $X'$ while the theorem still holds true?

Obviously, as my explanation of the posing process points out, the answer of my question may be lay on the non-"simple" cases of the theorem or [the more-general theorem of Stokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). Either this or that, please elaborate it simply to me. In addition, I haven't study the Stokes' theorem yet.

Thanks in advance!